# MySQL get all users who was in work in exact week

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: users and users_arrivals, I need to create a list of users who was in work in specific ranges of dates. Users table looks like:

```
| id | firstName | lastName |
| -- | --------- | -------- |
| 1  | John 1    | Test 1   |
| 2  | John 2    | Test 2   |
| 3  | John 3    | Test 3   |
| 4  | John 4    | Test 4   |
```

users_arrivals:

```
| id | user_id | start_date |  end_date  | 
| -- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|  1 |       1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-30 |
|  2 |       2 | 2022-09-22 | 2022-09-25 |
|  3 |       3 | 2022-09-19 | 2022-09-25 |
```

And now I need to get all users who was in work between dates 2022-09-19 and 2022-09-25 but some users have range 2022-09-01 and 2022-09-30 and also should be returned. I tried to make SQL like that but it only returns users who have range smaller or same as 2022-09-19 and 2022-09-25. How I can get users who have bigger range?

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_arrivals po ON po.user_id = u.id
WHERE po.start_date BETWEEN '2022-09-19' AND '2022-09-25' AND po.end_date    BETWEEN '2022-09-19' AND '2022-09-25' 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_arrivals po ON po.user_id = u.id
WHERE '2022-09-19' BETWEEN po.start_date AND po.end_date    
OR    '2022-09-25' BETWEEN po.start_date AND po.end_date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/xf54UzPg